# CSS: opacity animation with address element and img

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'd like to ask you for advice. I have a navigation bar with a dropdown button. In that I added to every items a small image with an opacity animation. So when you put a cursor on that image it appears and the other way around.
My problem is that I don't know how to match the item with image, because I want to see also the image while putting cursor on the item. I'm not sure if I should match it in HTML or CSS.

Here's a little of my code:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  cursor: auto;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #cddc39;
  font-size: large;
}


/**ODKAZY: TEXT */

.bar-item {
  border-color: #cddc39;
  color: #cddc39;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.klik {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 40px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0, 25s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.klik:hover,
.bar-item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar dropdown-click">
  <div class="dropdown-click">
    <button class="w3-button" onclick="myFunction()">
      <img class="topnav-pic menu" src="images/icon-navbar.png" alt="navigační tlačítko"/>
    </button>
    <div id="demo" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#pt_about" class="bar-item"><img class="klik" src="images/favicon.png">about me</a>
      <a href="#pt_studium" class="bar-item"><img class="klik" src="images/favicon.png">study</a>
      <a href="#pt_prace" class="bar-item"><img class="klik" src="images/favicon.png">my work</a>
      <a href="#para" class="bar-item"><img class="klik" src="images/favicon.png">hobbies</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a combination of HTML and CSS to create a navigation bar with a dropdown button and images. Your CSS is defining the styling for the dropdown menu and images, and your HTML is defining the structure of the navigation bar.

To match each item with its associated image, you could wrap each item and its corresponding image in a container element, such as a  or . For example, you could modify your HTML like this:

```
 <div class="navbar dropdown-click">   <div class="dropdown-click">
        <button class="w3-button" onclick="myFunction()">
          <img class="topnav-pic menu" src="images/icon-navbar.png" alt="navigační tlačítko"/>
        </button>
        <div id="demo" class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#pt_about" class="bar-item"><span class="item-text">about me</span><img class="klik"
    src="images/favicon.png" alt="about me"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#pt_studium" class="bar-item"><span class="item-text">study</span><img class="klik"
    src="images/favicon.png" alt="study"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#pt_prace" class="bar-item"><span class="item-text">my work</span><img class="klik"
    src="images/favicon.png" alt="my work"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#para" class="bar-item"><span class="item-text">hobbies</span><img class="klik"
    src="images/favicon.png" alt="hobbies"></a>
          </div>
        </div>   </div> </div>
```